# where can i find settings for wifi internal scan period

Tags: wi-fi, settings

I have already found some [guide](http://www.droidforums.net/forum/droid-general-discussions/27795-wifi-search-time-interval.html) related to this. But my experience is that if `wifi.supplicant_scan_interval = 15`
my device scans for wifi with 60s period
so I dont think that this is the right parameter for that. Any suggestions?
**Edited:** here is my build.prop:

```
# begin build properties
# autogenerated by buildinfo.sh
ro.build.id=GRK39F
ro.build.display.id=GRK39F
ro.build.version.incremental=eng.paul.30092011.041430
ro.build.version.sdk=10
ro.build.version.codename=REL
ro.build.version.release=2.3.6
ro.build.date=Fri Aug 30 04:14:55 EDT 2011
ro.build.date.utc=0
ro.build.type=user
ro.build.user=paul
ro.build.host=paul-VM
ro.build.tags=test-keys
ro.product.model=U20i
ro.product.brand=Sony Ericsson
ro.product.name=mimmi
ro.product.device=mimmi
ro.product.board=mimmi
ro.product.cpu.abi=armeabi-v6l
ro.product.cpu.abi2=armeabi
ro.product.manufacturer=Sony Ericsson
ro.product.locale.language=en
ro.product.locale.region=US
ro.wifi.channels=14
ro.board.platform=msm7k
# ro.build.product is obsolete; use ro.product.device
ro.build.product=mimmi
# Do not try to parse ro.build.description or .fingerprint
ro.build.description=passion-user 2.3.6 GRK39F 189904 release-keys
ro.build.fingerprint=google/passion/passion:2.3.6/GRK39F/189904:user/release-keys
# end build properties

#
# ADDITIONAL_BUILD_PROPERTIES
#
keyguard.no_require_sim=true
ro.ril.hsxpa=2
ro.ril.hsupa.category=5
ro.ril.def.agps.mode=2
ro.media.dec.jpeg.memcap=20000000
rild.libpath=/system/lib/libril-qc-1.so
rild.libargs=-d /dev/smd0
wifi.interface=wlan0
wifi.supplicant_scan_interval=15
ro.ril.def.agps.mode=2
ro.ril.def.agps.feature=1
ro.opengles.version=131072
ro.com.google.locationfeatures=1
ro.com.google.networklocation=1
ro.ril.enable.a52=1
ro.ril.enable.a53=1
ro.media.enc.file.format=3gp,mp4
ro.media.enc.vid.codec=m4v,h263
ro.media.enc.vid.h263.width=176,640
ro.media.enc.vid.h263.height=144,480
ro.media.enc.vid.h263.bps=64000,1600000
ro.media.enc.vid.h263.fps=1,30
ro.media.enc.vid.m4v.width=176,640
ro.media.enc.vid.m4v.height=144,480
ro.media.enc.vid.m4v.bps=64000,1600000
ro.media.enc.vid.m4v.fps=1,30
ro.media.dec.aud.wma.enabled=1
ro.media.dec.vid.wmv.enabled=1
ro.media.dec.aud.divx.enabled=1
ro.media.dec.vid.xvid.enabled=1
settings.display.autobacklight=0
media.stagefright.enable-player=true
media.stagefright.enable-meta=true
media.stagefright.enable-scan=true
media.stagefright.enable-http=true
keyguard.no_require_sim=true

#MT and LCD
ro.sf.lcd_density=120
qemu.sf.lcd_density=120
ro.product.multi_touch_enabled=true
ro.product.max_max_num_touch=2

dalvik.vm.execution-mode=int:jit
dalvik.vm.heapsize=32m
ro.compcache.default=0
ro.rommanager.developerid=cyanogenmod
ro.url.legal=http://www.google.com/intl/%s/mobile/android/basic/phone-legal.html
ro.url.legal.android_privacy=http://www.google.com/intl/%s/mobile/android/basic/privacy.html
ro.com.google.clientidbase=android-sonyericsson
ro.com.android.wifi-watchlist=GoogleGuest
ro.setupwizard.enterprise_mode=1
ro.com.android.dateformat=MM-dd-yyyy
ro.com.android.dataroaming=false
ro.config.ringtone=MiniCM7Pro.mp3
ro.config.notification_sound=DontPanic.ogg
ro.config.alarm_alert=alarm.ogg
ro.modversion=MiniCM7 Pro V16 Pre-Final
ro.setupwizard.mode=OPTIONAL
net.bt.name=Android
dalvik.vm.stack-trace-file=/data/anr/traces.txt

#SEMC
persist.service.xloud.enable=1
persist.service.swiqi.enable=1
ro.semc.timescape_keys=Sony_Ericsson_Xperia
ro.semc.sound_effects_enabled=true
ro.semc.xloud.supported=true
ro.service.swiqi.supported=true
ro.semc.batt.capacity=950
ro.semc.batt.test.consumption=150
ro.semc.batt.test.z_threshold=50
ro.semc.batt.test.min_level=60
```

**Edit2:** The scanning period is depending on the connectivity as well. Means if the phone establishes a WI-FI connection, then the scanning period will be different from the `wifi.supplicant_scan_interval`. Also when the phone get into idle state (around 10 mins of inactivity) the scanning period will be 10 min.

Comment: Look at post #4 of that guide you have enclosed in your question.

Comment: Have I missed something else not mentioned in my question?

Comment: Are you rooted? Do you have access to `/system` as rw? Can you paste in the full contents of `build.prop` into this? Does your Wifi driver have the capability to set the scan interval via `build.prop`? Also, *point to remember*, 60seconds is better and less taxing on the battery instead of 15seconds!

Comment: @t0mm13b yes, the phone is rooted, build.prop is added. Actually I am writing an app using wifi, and i measured the scan period which was 60s. Yes it better then 15, but I would like to know where this 60s comes from. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This property comes from during build-time and is extremely, dependant on the wifi driver, for each and every device tree that gets integrated into the build of Android, there's what's called an *overlay*, this overlay may contain extras pertaining to the said device in question.

In fact, its rather, an XML document that gets parsed during build and "overlays" or "overwrites" the standard Android defaults, such as animation speed, etc.

This pertinent information of this comes from the device's `overlay/frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/config.xml` which contains the very exact line:

```
<!-- Boolean indicating whether the wifi chipset has background scan support -->
<bool translatable="false" name="config_wifi_background_scan_support">true</bool>
```

From that, that is telling the build, to say, that the property `wifi.supplicant_scan_interval` is supported and can be used dynamically from the `build.prop` file found in the `/system` directory, which in turn, is read from the Android's native binary executable `wpa_supplicant`.

However, it must be said, it depends on the Wifi Driver to support that, and how much integration of the Wifi functionality is within the frameworks. To find the exact source can be found in `external/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.c`, around lines 2459:

```
#ifdef ANDROID
    char scan_prop[PROPERTY_VALUE_MAX];
    char *endp;
    if (property_get("wifi.supplicant_scan_interval", scan_prop, "5") != 0) {
        wpa_s->scan_interval = (int)strtol(scan_prop, &endp, 0);
        if (endp == scan_prop) {
            wpa_s->scan_interval = 5;
        }
    }
#endif
```

default here on Gingerbread is 5secs, again the mileage will vary depending on the version of `wpa_supplicant` used, there was two versions, `wpa_supplicant_6` which was broken under ICS, and the newer version `wpa_supplicant_8`, despite saying that, it may no longer be supported now with the newer releases.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! However I cannot find these files your are mentioning: so what is the exact path to the .c file, and .xml? I am using Root explorer, but no overlay/ and no external/ folder in root

Comment: It is in the AOSP source code, you are not going to find it in Android ROM that you have currently in your handset, the details mentioned above would be if and when the AOSP source gets pulled down to your machine prior to building Android.

Comment: So what I understand is that Wifi scan period time can be 60s even wifi.supplicant_scan_interval = 15. And I cannot check it, just measure the exact time?

Comment: If the `build.prop` has that property in place but does not actually scan for that specified period, the binary  executable in Android, `wpa_supplicant` is not patched in to have the capability to read that property from `build.prop`. **BTW** to make it clear, its stated *build-time* meaning before compiling Android which is what my answer is pointing out.

Comment: so if this is the case, then I cannot modify the scan period, right?

Comment: That is dependent on if the Android binary executable `wpa_supplicant` is patched in or not! For all you know, it could be ignoring it and not care whether its specified in the `build.prop`... :)

Comment: Since my settings is 15, but the real value is 60 then I assume that I cannot modify it - am I right? asking again, or maybe I should try to modify to 30, and see what happens.

Comment: Assuming the binary is not patched in, then you cannot modify it.

Comment: and the only way is to figure out whether is patched or not is to try modifing the period via `wifi.supplicant_scan_interval`, right? - last question

Comment: Try it! :) One thing, if you do see that it does not work, then make a backup copy of the binary, if you intend to copy it elsewhere from another ROM for example, *that could break the wifi functionality* due to that binary, not knowing how to bring up the Wifi, as it may not have the chipset driver compiled into it, based on the actual Wifi chipset used in your device!